# Getting error while doing groupby then use sum() function

Tags: python, pandas

when I try to group by  using my first approach its work fine:
1. it is working fine.

```
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])['x','y','z'].sum()
```

2. its not woking.

```
s=x,y,z
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])s.split(",").sum()
```

3. even this is not working

```
s=['x','y','z']
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])s.sum()
```

in all the above cases only 1 is working fine rest are not working but I am supplying the same list 
after every groupby.
help me to get them out of with this situation or suggest some other way to do sum after groupby because I don't want to follow the 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create nested list after `groupby` - `[[]]`:

```
s='x,y,z'
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])[s.split(",")].sum()

s=['x','y','z']
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])[s].sum()
```

Because also working:

```
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])[['x','y','z']].sum()
```

like:

```
n=df.groupby(['A','B'])['x','y','z'].sum()
```

Comment: what about my second approach df.groupby(['A','B'])[s.split(",')].sum().